# How to disable HTML5 features in Chrome to test fallback?

Tags: html, testing, modernizr

I'm using the Modernizr library to detect HTML5 `<video>` tag. I wish to temporarily disable HTML5 features in Chrome to test a fallback Flash method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would a use a tool like IEtester and emulate an old Internet Explorer Browser (IE 6 for example), that doesnt Support html5.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but this post is the top Google result. I found a better answer. Simply replace your `<video>` tag with some non-HTML5 tag, like `<notavideo>`. It'll behave as if the feature is not supported, and show the valid html within instead.

Example, before:

```
<video src="movie.mp4">
   Your browser does not support videos.
</video>
```

After:

```
<notavideo src="movie.mp4">
    Your browser does not support videos.
</notavideo>
```

Remember to change it back to `<video>` when you're done testing :)